# How to match any thing dosen't contain a specific word using RegExp

Tags: php, regex

How to match any thing dosen't contain a specific word using RegExp

Ex:
Match any string doesn't contain 'aabbcc'

```
bbbaaaassdd // Match this
aabbaabbccaass // Reject this
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use negative lookahead:

```
(?!.*?aabbcc)^.*$
```

#### Live Demo: http://www.rubular.com/r/4Exbf7UdDv

**PHP Code:**

```
$str = 'aabbaabbccaass'; //or whatever
if (preg_match('/(?!.*?aabbcc)^.*$/', $str))
   echo "accepted\n";
else
   echo "rejected\n";
```

Comment: You're welcome. If this answer helped you solve your problem, please consider marking it as "accepted", so users facing a similar problem in the future will be able to see it easily.

Answer (score 3):

If you're just after this sequence of characters, don't use a Regular Expression. Use `strpos()`.

```
if (strpos('aabbaabbccaass', 'aabbcc') !== false) {
    echo 'Reject this.'
}
```

**Note:** Be sure to read the warning in the manual about [`strpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) return values.

Comment: Iam asking for using this concept with complex expressions

Comment: Understood. However, it is good to know when Regular Expressions are not the right tool for the job. As such, I will leave this answer based on your example.

Answer (score 2):

try this to avoid some sequences of letters :

```
^((?!aabbcc).)*$
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
if(preg_match('/aabbcc/', $string) == 0) {
   [ OK ]
}
else {
   [ NOT OK ]
}
```

Comment: I think you want to flip the OK and NOT OK

Comment: The OP said **Match any string doesn't contain 'aabbcc'** so no, I look for a non-match

Comment: Ah, Im not familiar with PHP, didnt know 0 meant not match.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to describe a substring that doesn't contain *aabbcc*:

```
(?>[^a]++|a(?!abbcc))*
```

*for the whole string, just add anchors (`^` `$`)*